# UITableView indexPath null issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have this issue with my UITableView. When i drag the table so that the bottom row is half way up, i get a crash. When I basically drag the bottom row all the way as up as i can get it. The code snippet is below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSString *section = [[browseCategoriesDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *objectsForSection = [browseCategoriesDictionary objectForKey:section];

    NSString *cellValue = [objectsForSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x7C/255.0 green:0x7E/255.0 blue:0xBB/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [cellDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[cellIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Please check the different data sources that you are using are not returning nil values, it may result in a crash.